# Extracting drawings from a model

Tags: camera

I have made a model of a part and need 2D cad drawings. How do I get high resolution drawings from a 3D model? I tried using flat shading and taking screenshots of it, but that is too small. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzhfC.png

Comment: yes fillerfillerfiller

Answer (score 1):

This is my object rendered normally in EEVEE.

[image]

First set the Main Camera to Orthographic.

[image]

Move Camera to desired position. Then toggle the camera view with View > Cameras > Active Camera. Or <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

[image]

Use the Orthographic Scale slider in the Camera options to fit the object to frame.

[image]

Under Render Properties. Check the Freestyle box.

[image]

Under View Layer Properties. There are lots of options to play around with to get desired effect, such as line colour, thickness, texture etc.

[image]

F12 to Render.

[image]

If there are edges that you need to be affected by Freestyle that are not automatically drawn. The easiest way for a predictable result is to Select the object and go into Edit Mode. Select the edges you want to be drawn, right click then select Mark Freestyle Edge. Freestyle edges are highlighted green. Make sure that View Layer Properties > Freestyle Line Set > Edge Type > Edge Mark is checked for it to show in the render.

[image]
[image]

Comment: holy cow! thanks for the great explanation, I'll go see if it works

Comment: nope, it ain't working do i need a light? is this blender 2.3?

Comment: Should just work with environmental light.